# Abort docker build if cache cannot be used

Tags: git, docker, githooks

As part of a `git` pre-push hook I build a `docker` image. 
This build can take several minutes and in the meantime the connection to the remote timeouts.
Therefore, I would like `docker` to break the build as soon as it detects a layer that cannot be used from its cache. I understand there is no `dry-run` build, is there some other trick that I missed?

In other words, as soon as docker actually tried to build a layer it should stop and return a non-zero code.

Comment: Could you say a little bit more about your use case?  It sounds like you want `docker build` to stop if it hasn't already built the exact image it'd be trying to build, so either it runs end to end without doing any work or aborts.

Comment: That's what I want indeed. The pre-push hook should fail if the image is outdated. The user should then build the image separately.